# GetOpenFileName() and GetSaveFileName() make GetAsyncKeyState() stop working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gcc, windows-10

`GetOpenFileName()` and `GetSaveFileName()` make `GetAsyncKeyState()` stop working.

(Note: I am also using `getch()` from `<conio.h>` in some places, if that is any use)

A little example (UNTESTED):

```cpp
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

#define keyPressed(x) GetAsyncKeyState(x) & 0x8000

int main () {
  while (true) {
    if (keyPressed('w')) {
      cout << "W pressed\n";
      break;
    }
  }

  OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
  char Buffer[300];
  std::fill(Buffer, Buffer + 300, '\0');
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
  ofn.hwndOwner = GetForegroundWindow();
  ofn.lpstrFile = Buffer;
  ofn.nMaxFile = 300;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER;
  ofn.lpstrFilter = NULL;
  ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
  ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
  ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
  ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
  ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
  if (!GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) {
    cout << "Error\n";
  }

  while (true) {
    if (keyPressed('w')) {
      cout << "W pressed\n";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You do realize that you're checking the F8 key, not the W key.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RaymondChen sorry it was meant to be capital W, i think stackoverflow messed it up

Comment: @IInspectable when i use GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName, GetAsyncKeyState stops working.

Comment: @kenan238 the value passed to `GetAsyncKeyState` is not necessarily an ASCII value, you need to use the value for the [Virtual Key Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) so using a character literal is not recommended.

Comment: Alright but i just speedrunned the example but in the original source code it works with char literals.

Comment: *"GetAsyncKeyState stops working"* - Setting aside what that actually means, I was asking about the problem you are trying to solve. Now it's very rare that polling is the correct solution to any problem in Windows, so I have to assume that it isn't here either. Again, what **problem** are you trying to solve? (I'm expressly not asking what **solution** you want to implement.)

Comment: GetForegroundWindow as the owner is usually wrong, use NULL.

Comment: @IInspectable So the situation is: I am checking for a keypress with GetAsyncKeyState every frame, and i have a save option, when the user presses save, it shows up a Save As dialog (using GetSaveFileName) and then, after the dialog pops up, GetAsyncKeyState stops working

Comment: @Anders thanks for the help, i'll try that

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: @kenan238 "*GetAsyncKeyState stops working*" - but what does that MEAN to you, though? WHAT stops working exactly? Be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to @Anders, setting ofn.hwndOwner to NULL worked. Thanks!

I didn't need to poll in another thread or use Virtual Key Codes but thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure `GetAsyncKeyState` is working as normal but you are not actually calling it while the open/save dialog is open because these modal dialogs run their own message loop and the function does not return back to your code until you close the dialog.

You could run the `GetAsyncKeyState` loop in another thread and then it would work but you should not do that because polling in a loop is bad. Use `RegisterHotKey` or a low-level [keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa).

And finally, `GetAsyncKeyState` checks a virtual key code, not arbitrary ASCII characters.

Comment: Hmm, i'll see with that

Comment: I stop calling GetAsyncKeyState while the dialog is open, but when it closes, my program resumes and GetAsyncKeyState does nothing